# message passing between cli script and chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, command-line-interface

I'm reading about [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) in chrome extensions. I want to create an extension that will comunicate with a cli script and have the ability to start and stop it. I want also to integrate a counter badge that will inform me about updates from the cli script. Is this possible or I need to write an electron app to achive this?

Comment: Any language/environment is fine as long as it reads/writes stdio as shown in the nativeMessaging documentation. Note that this API starts a new instance of the registered app so if you want to communicate with some existing stuff you will need to do it inside the registered app and send the results back to extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm at the moment I have a node cli script that is running until the terminal is closed. As I know it will use `stdio` to log messages in terminal. I've seen the exentison sample but I'm confused about implementation in my actual script. Can you help with a sample?

Comment: I don't have any samples. I guess I need to rephrase what I said: the extension can't communicate with an already running stuff directly. It can start a native app. That app will communicate with the cli script and then send the results to the extension.

Comment: ok, more clear. If I understand I need to convert the cli script into an electron app that is able to comunicate with the extension and vice versa. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Just in case I wasn't clear, this app will be also started by the extension.